# How do I write a map object to a csv?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a map object x such that

```
list(x)
```

produces a list. I am presently trying:

```
def writethis(name, mapObject):
    import csv
    with open(name, 'wb') as f:
        csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',').writerows(list(mapObject))
```

but get either get an error saying the list produced isn't a valid sequence, or, if I have another function pass writethis a map object or list in the interpreter, a blank CSV file.

I'm not very familiar with the csv module. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

First, note that you open files for CSV writing differently in Python 3.  You want

```
with open(name, 'w', newline='') as f:
```

instead.  Second, `writerows` expects a sequence of sequences, and it seems like you're only passing it a sequence.  If you only have one row to write, then

```
def writethis(name, mapObject):
    with open(name, 'w', newline='') as f:
        csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',').writerow(list(mapObject))
```

should work.